# Pandas read_csv, ignore first cell

Tags: python, pandas

I have .csv file like this:

```
Str;  Int; Flt
  A;  123; 0.1
  B;  456; 0.2
  C;  789; 0.3
```

I want to get DataFrame like this

```
   Int; Flt
A; 123; 0.1
B; 456; 0.2
C; 789; 0.3
```

I read csv like this

```
df = pd.read_csv('data.csv', index_col=0, sep=";")
```

And the problem is that I can't use `df.loc["A", "Int"]` to get cell value.
If I drop `Str;` from csv everything works fine.

So the idea is to use first row as row names and first column as column names. I understand that first element can't be used both as col name and row name, is there any way to drop such ambigous value?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have a whitespace issue.

```py
import io
import pandas as pd

fp = io.StringIO('''
Str;  Int; Flt
  A;  123; 0.1
  B;  456; 0.2
  C;  789; 0.3
'''.strip())

df = pd.read_csv(fp, index_col=0, sep=";")

print("Index: ", df.index)
print("Columns: ", df.columns)

# Now look at the whitespace:
print(df.loc['  A','  Int'])
```

Yields:

```
Index:  Index(['  A', '  B', '  C'], dtype='object', name='Str')
Columns:  Index(['  Int', ' Flt'], dtype='object')
123
```

So when you get rid of `"Str"`, it appears you're dealing with the whitespace issue.

So instead do:

```py
df = pd.read_csv(fp, index_col=0, sep=";" , skipinitialspace=True)

print(df.loc['A','Int'])
```

Answer (score 2):

Use: `index_col='Str'` instead of `index_col=0`

Edited script:

```bash
import pandas as pd 

df = pd.read_csv("test.csv", sep=";", index_col='Str')

print(df.loc["A", "Int"])
```

> output: `123`

Comment: looks like I misused spaces in csv, everything works fine

Comment: @Demaunt why have you selected this as the correct answer? This code breaks for me.